# Issue with type inference in function overloading in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-inference, overload-resolution

Why the following example fails to compile?

```js
function mapObjectValues<I, O, K extends keyof any>(obj: Record<K, I>, map: (value: I, key: K) => O): Record<K, O>
function mapObjectValues<K extends keyof any, I extends Record<K, any>, O extends Record<K, any>>(obj: I, map: (value: I[K], key: K) => O[K]): O
function mapObjectValues<I, O>(obj: Record<keyof any, I>, map: (value: I, key: keyof any) => O): Record<keyof any, O>
function mapObjectValues<I, O>(_obj: Record<keyof any, I>, _map: (value: I, key: keyof any) => O): Record<keyof any, O> {
    throw "not relevant"
}

function checker(_input: Record<string, string>) { }

// compiles
checker(mapObjectValues({
    foo: "bar"
}, (_, k) => k))

// compiles
checker(mapObjectValues({
    ["foo"]: "bar"
}, (_, k) => k))

// fails with:
//
// Argument of type 'Record<string | number, string | number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, string>'.
//   'string' index signatures are incompatible.
//     Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
//       Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
checker(mapObjectValues({
    [{
        foo: "foo"
    }.foo]: "bar"
}, (_, k) => k))

// compiles
checker(mapObjectValues({
    [({
        foo: "foo"
    } as const).foo]: "bar"
}, (_, k) => k))
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcDyAjAVgU2gDVUAbEfAZwB4BJAGkU0YGlF8APKfMAE0sQBrfAE84wRKjAiAfAAo4eAFyIASoTgAnXtRaNaMxmnQq5ANzIUVDIaJUsAlIgC8Mpg5XqIWnXqYyAKFBIWAQUDBwCYksqXXYuHn5bMQkpEX147j4BLx9dRjTDJkzEnI1tfMlpGXlFXGsjDFMLcnxrAG0WAF1GYRF7J1cmTq6PJiDwaHgkY0jCKBJWmhtMWuU1cp0+8Sr0xANGk0RzGIbklW3U6UG3TDHcisvdxlWJkOnwrDx5xYpll-kAH06p5NtQnml9EVAcZmqd9r07Mkdmkbu5Qd5HqIUdIAYgAN4BRDExBQAAWmjgAHdEAAiMBwKCITT4Uj4CxgKC0gIAXwCbymYQgZMIwk0ckBMDA6BAUAxeUoUE0UoA5oxFcqwCqZE58Yg+QEAPSGxDeZDoGBsygBYWi-Di2bfaJLOSEkmIYBwOAqWnYVCabk8xgS3powQOBz842muDmy1UG0iiBiuSOqILGKUV1EkntWmeuC0ro+v0B3nBwGhlxucORo0m4CoS0CKkwclKev1xAAQU0KpAyB4TJ2UBE6HwiAA5A8dBrVYgAD6IMAD7D29VK+dLlfINeaGSTxAwAQMpmoSiUGAqsCobBs0lwRDof2oQfcTSIEdjifTsFzrUbpq2qTgAdF2xKTv+KqHlKvCcIgl7XqgUAgCyAj+hOUpms+sB3vgYHRu6AAq35TlBi7Lqu9owSejKSBeV43nhD6kqRkGblqoHge6iAkeOU47nuNHLnR56IUx95QI+o78exQFcbayb2qmEROhmLpurmmk8R6Xo+gW3LujyIEFsWdKloGFZVkMtZRia2HxtaikpmmPyZtm7rtB5Om6d6dIGTmxI8vRMZgIqDgmV6Zm+v6lnHJWQhhhGQA)

Is it a current limitation of type inference in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to `keyof` of indexed types returning `number | string`.

```
type foo = keyof { [x: string]: string; }
//   ^? type foo = number | string
```

Per [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48269#issuecomment-1068278045) on the Typescript GH, it works as intended.